# Exim - What's the mark of EOL in exigrep output?

Tags: awk, exim

I have exigrep output like this.

```bsh
2019-02-02 17:03:00 1gpxky-0005ky-Mk <= XXX@XXX.com U=XXXXX P=local S=14529 id=20190202160300.45640494.XXXXXX@XXXXX.com T="XXXXXXXXX" for XXXXX@gmail.com
2019-02-02 17:03:00 1gpxky-0005ky-Mk Sender identification U=XXXXX D=XXXXX.com S=XXXXX@XXXXX.com
2019-02-02 17:03:00 1gpxky-0005ky-Mk SMTP connection outbound 1549123380 1gpxky-0005ky-Mk XXXXX.com XXXXX@gmail.com
2019-02-02 17:03:01 1gpxky-0005ky-Mk => XXXX@gmail.com R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=yes C="250 2.0.0 OK 1549123381 m21si11695854lfc.90 - gsmtp"
2019-02-02 17:03:01 1gpxky-0005ky-Mk Completed

2019-02-02 15:48:22 1gpwaj-00081N-5J H=mx2.XXXXX.pl [XX.XX.XX.XX]:15240 Warning: "SpamAssassin as takapara detected message as NOT spam (2.4)"
2019-02-02 15:48:22 1gpwaj-00081N-5J H=mx2.XXXXX.pl [XX.XX.XX.XX]:15240 Warning: Message has been scanned: no virus or other harmful content was found
2019-02-02 15:48:22 1gpwaj-00081N-5J <= XXX.XXXX@XXXX.pl H=mx2.XXXX.pl [XX.XX.XX.XX]:15240 P=esmtp S=72014 id=9c38a455-1b57-404a-ae68-87ed816473a8 T="XXXXXXXXXX" for XXX@XXXX.com
2019-02-02 15:48:23 1gpwaj-00081N-5J => XXXX <XXXX@XXXX.com> R=virtual_user T=dovecot_virtual_delivery C="250 2.0.0 <XXXX@XXXX.com> +A/zNratVVyfaQAADQHPYA Saved"
2019-02-02 15:48:23 1gpwaj-00081N-5J Completed
```

And I have some of these - but after done awk regex style "grep" I've got all mail addresses (even that in middle of output of single "block" - second output in example)

I search for just grep through first line 5th thing with awk (sender mail address wo is on my server) but `\n` don't work.

I have code like this:

```
# cat /var/log/exim_mainlog | grep 2019-02-02 | exigrep {user_name} | awk '/^([0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*) ([0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*) ([0-9a-zA-Z]*-[0-9a-zA-Z]*-[0-9a-zA-Z]*) (<=).*\n/ {print $5}'
```

How to define EOL here?

Comment: Can you add the expected output to your question? It sounds like `awk 'NF > 4 && $4 == "<=" { print $5 }'` will work, with some complications if the email address itself contains white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`awk`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04) and [**`grep`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) use '$' for the end-of-line marker (a feature of POSIX regular expressions).  **`\n`** isn't part of that, whether [basic regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (the default for grep) or [extended regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (an option with grep, standard with awk).

See [*9.3.8 BRE Expression Anchoring*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_08):

> A *`<dollar-sign>`* ( '$' ) shall be an anchor when used as the last character of an entire BRE. The implementation may treat a *`<dollar-sign>`* as an anchor when used as the last character of a subexpression. The *`<dollar-sign>`* shall anchor the expression (or optionally subexpression) to the end of the string being matched; the *`<dollar-sign>`* can be said to match the end-of-string following the last character.

From the comment - if you want to print only the first match in awk, you could do something like this to the chunk

```
{print $5}
```

replacing that with

```
{if (found) next; found = 1; print $5; }
```

Comment: Ok thank you :) but I still get other mails... so it must test each line... it's possible to test just first line of each "message route"?

Comment: You could filter the results with "head -n 1", or set a variable in the awk stage telling it to skip the remaining lines (using the **`next`** keyword).

Comment: Don't work, give me totally unreleated mail address - just one but I've got idea so if it will work I will put in in edit of question

Answer (score 0):

The command mentioned above should work:

```
awk 'NR==1{print $5}' filename
```

Comment: It's fine, but I've found that it's only take by first "response" - not by all blocks from log - because exim mainlog is built `<block><space><block><space>` and in block are all data so I search only for "<=" in first line and show 5th "word" (column = mail)

Comment: ok will check and update

Comment: Because this `cat /var/log/exim_mainlog | exigrep root | exigrep "<=" | awk 'NR==1{print $5}'` (for example) works perfect for as I said "first block".. on test environment (I don't have now access to production env to see on bigger scale how it's works)

Comment: Keep in mind that that's different from the first *match*: it's saying to print what's on the first *row*.